# Can several instances of IWbemObjectSink::Indicate run concurrently?

Tags: c++, winapi, concurrency, wmi

I am writing a C++ application to record created processes on Windows using WMI, as in [this example provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer-asynchronously). As you can see in the example code, the application provides an event sink with the method `EventSink::Indicate()`, which then is called asynchronously by WMI when a new process is created.

My question is if there are any guarantees about different callbacks being sequential, so that no two callbacks can ever run concurrently? This is a worry for me because my implementation of the `Indicate()` method sometimes modifies an attribute of the `EventSink` object, and I want to avoid a data race, obviously. Should I put the data behind a mutex to coordinate, or is this guaranteed not to happen?

Comment: you can very easy check this, say insert `MessageBox` in `Indicate` and start 2+ new processes. will be 2+ `MessageBox` or only one at time ? think can be multiple if you use `COINIT_MULTITHREADED`

Comment: What does the first line of code in the example do?

Comment: Call `CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);` It works well in my test. You may not need to worry about this.